# What does Get without clusterKey return in ScalarDB

Tags: scalardb

In `ScalarDB`, the library which provides ACID functionality on top of `Cassandra`, what does `Get` return if `clustering key` is not present and there are multiple rows in the database for same partition key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Get` without clustering key fails and throws `InvalidUsageException` when there are multiple rows with the same partition key.
You can use `Scan` for retrieving multiple rows with the same partition key.